# Increment the Nth number in the line

Tags: number-formatting

Ctrl-A is very useful for incrementing the first number in line,  but what if the number you want to increment is not the first one?

for an example, if  want to make,

```
Section. 1-1
Section. 1-2
Section. 1-3
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Do you want a solution that would work no matter what text is on the line, or a solution that would work for your example? And do you want to increment the second number on every line, or just one of them?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am looking for a solution that works with no matter what else is on the line. and I think I want to find the one that works for one line, so I can expand it to work with multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found a way to do this. I'm sure somebody has a better suggestion, but this is a start.
first of all,

```
Ctrl-A jumps the cursor to the next number and increments, and
Ctrl-x jumps the cursor to the next number and decrements,
```

combine this with a search,

```
/\d\+
```

which simply gets your cursor to the next number, you can make a macro to do this.

for the example question,

```
qa
^
/\d\+
n
ctrl-x
q
```

will make a macro that increments the second number of a given line. A trick is to have the n(ext) to get to the second number, and use ctrl-X instead of ctrl-A in this case, because vi thinks that hyphen as a negative sign. If you use ctrl-a, it actually decrements the subsection number.

Now, we can use the n(ext) to increment any nth number. 
I mean, first type,

```
section 1-3.2.2.10
```

then, put the cursor to that line, then

```
qa
yy
p
/\d\+
3n
ctrl-a
q
```

to record a macro, then,

```
4@a
```

will make,

```
Section 1-3.2.2.10
Section 1-3.2.3.10
Section 1-3.2.4.10
Section 1-3.2.5.10
Section 1-3.2.6.10
```

Alternatively, (Thank you, Rich!)
If we are incrementing the last number, we can do it much simply,

```
qa
yy
p
$
ctrl-a
q
```

then

```
4@a
```

to get

```
section 1-3.2.2.10
section 1-3.2.2.11
section 1-3.2.2.12
section 1-3.2.2.13
section 1-3.2.2.14
```

Comment: Is the example at the end simplified deliberately? `$` seems like a simpler way to get to the last number on the line in this example!

Comment: Thank you, Rich! Yes, that works! I did not realize it. I edited it to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: If your numbers are in a column, you can also do it using visual mode (without a macro), too. For your specific example: `yy4p$<C-V>3jg<C-A>`. See `:help v_g_CTRL-A`